# ios assigning value to a string from an array

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray

So I have a basic array:

```
NSMutableArray *answerButtonsArrayWithURL = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:self.playView.coverURL1, self.playView.coverURL2, self.playView.coverURL3, self.playView.coverURL4, nil];
```

The objects inside are strings. I want to access a random object from that array

```
int rndValueForURLS = arc4random() % 3;
```

and assigning it a value. I've tried manny different approaches but my recent one is

```
[[answerButtonsArrayWithURL objectAtIndex:rndValueForURLS] stringByAppendingString:[self.coverFromRightAnswer objectAtIndex:self.rndValueForQuestions]];
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign it. You're already building the new value like that:

```
NSString *oldValue = answerButtonsArrayWithURL[rndValueForURLS];
NSString *newValue = [oldValue stringByAppendingString:[self.coverFromRightAnswer objectAtIndex:self.rndValueForQuestions]];
```

The part you're missing :

```
answerButtonsArrayWithURL[rndValueForURLS] = newValue;
```

Above would be the way to replace the **immutable** string with another. If the strings are *mutable*, that is, they were created as `NSMutableString`, you could do:

```
NSMutableString *value = answerButtonsArrayWithURL[rndValueForURLS];
[value appendString:[self.coverFromRightAnswer objectAtIndex:self.rndValueForQuestions]];
```

---

**Note**:

Everywhere I replace the notation :

```
[answerButtonsArrayWithURL objectAtIndex:rndValueForURLS];
```

with the new equivalent and IMO more readable:

```
answerButtonsArrayWithURL[rndValueForURLS];
```

Comment: thanks a lot. the first solution didn't work but making them mutable, witch I should've done in the first place, worked.